# Populate ComboBox with one value of the HashMap(Object)

Tags: java, netbeans, dictionary

I have a ComboBox that I want to populate with Product names. I have a Class called Producto which has the values:

```
private String name;
private String code;
private int price;
```

So I created a HashMap like this:

```
Map(Integer, Producto) mapProducto=new HashMap<Integer, Producto>();
```

I also have a method to populate this HashMap:

```
Producto stockProducto=new Producto();
stockProducto.setNomProducto("Steel Bike");
stockProducto.setCodeProducto("BIC001");
stockProducto.setPrice(190000);
getMapProducto().put(1, stockProducto);

stockProducto.setNomProducto("Aluminium Bike");
stockProducto.setCodeProducto("BIC002");
stockProducto.setPrice(290000);
getMapProducto().put(1, stockProducto);
```

After that I populate the ComboBox:

```
Iterator iter=getMapProducto().keySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
this.cboNomProducto.addItem(getMapProducto().get(iter.next()));
}
```

But since it receives an Object of the Producto type, it populates the Combo with weird code, which I guess is the memory direction of the object. But I want to populate the ComboBox with just the Name of the Product. How can I get only this value of the Object Producto?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is my solution worked for you ?

Comment: @FaisalAli like I said that worked. Thanks a lot. BUt the only problem now is that I filled my Map with two items, but the ComboBox is filled with the last item twice. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Iterator iter=getMapProducto().keySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
    this.cboNomProducto.addItem(getMapProducto().get(iter.next()).getNomProducto());
}
```

**Details:**

`getMapProducto().get(iter.next())` will return `Producto` object which can't be directly set to the combobox, you have to get Product Name from that object and add into the combobox.

**Edit**

```
Producto stockProducto=new Producto();
stockProducto.setNomProducto("Steel Bike");
stockProducto.setCodeProducto("BIC001");
stockProducto.setPrice(190000);
getMapProducto().put(1, stockProducto);

stockProducto = new Producto(); // You forgot this
stockProducto.setNomProducto("Aluminium Bike");
stockProducto.setCodeProducto("BIC002");
stockProducto.setPrice(290000);
getMapProducto().put(1, stockProducto);
```

If you don't create new `Producto` then the same object is referenced twice in `HashMap` instead of 2 different `Producto`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The only problem now is that I filled my Map with two items, but the ComboBox is filled with the last item twice. Why is that?

Comment: I have edited the answer.. Look at this, Hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: I was actually adding that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please mark this as a correct answer if it addressed your query. Thanks :)

Comment: I understand, that this answer was accepted, it is a quick solution. But it states the simply wrong: "...  will return Producto object which can't be directly set to the combobox ...". It is imho the preferred way to add the instances of Producto to the JComboBox instead of simple Strings. Look at my answer or the added JavaDoc of addItem.

Comment: Well I only have expertise in java by using it in android so I have no idea about the convention in JComboBox.. Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `toString`. Here you have to only return the wanted `name`. I assume you get the standard `toString` value which prints the classname together with the class instance hash value.

**Edit 1:** `JComboBox` always derives the displayed text from the inserted objects `toString` method. It allows definitly to insert complex Objects and not only Strings. You can look that up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28E%29). Therefore include in your `Producto` class the following method

```
public String toString () {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to override that method, because everythime I want to override something, Netbeans don't allow it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't meant an error. The code blocks are blocked.

Comment: Class Producto has locked parts?

Comment: I saw the other answer was already accepted. Nevertheless I did not wanted my message in the unformatted way it was.